# How to fix "SQLException was unhandled"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

Im having an error when running this project

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Additional information: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

```
namespace Project.DAL
{

    public static class NativeSqlDb
    {
        public static string ConStr
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project.Properties.Settings.QuestionDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }

        public static DataTable ExecuteReader(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dt");
            con.Open();  //Im having error on this part sqlexception was unhandle

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        }

        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            int sayi = 0;
            try
            {
                sayi = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return sayi;
        }

        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, params SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            int sayi = 0;
            foreach (SqlParameter p in param)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
            try
            {
                sayi = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return sayi;
        }

        public static object ExecuteScalar(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            object o;
            try
            {
                o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return o;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are not connected to your sql server

Comment: Can you connect SSMS to this sql server?

Comment: Looks like you are writing the variable name inside a string. Please use the variable name directly: ConnectionStrings[Project.Properties.Settings.QuestionDbConnectionString]

Comment: You can also use: "GetConnectionString" function from "ConfigurationExtensions" class.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: i am connected to sql server but still getting the error