# "SQLException was unhandled"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

Im having an error when running this project

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

```
namespace Project.DAL
{

    public static class NativeSqlDb
    {
        public static string ConStr
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project.Properties.Settings.QuestionDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }

        public static DataTable ExecuteReader(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dt");
            con.Open();  //Im having error on this part sqlexception was unhandle

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        }

        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            int sayi = 0;
            try
            {
                sayi = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return sayi;
        }

        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, params SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            int sayi = 0;
            foreach (SqlParameter p in param)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
            try
            {
                sayi = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return sayi;
        }

        public static object ExecuteScalar(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            object o;
            try
            {
                o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return o;
        }

    }
}
```

I am connected to my SQL server but I'm still getting the error.

EDIT: Breakpoint screenshot.

[image: connection string]

EDIT:

[image: management studio login]

[image: management studio login]

Comment: "I am connected to my SQL server but im still getting the error" - um, no, you're not - that's the exact problem: "The server was not found or was not accessible." - so; can you clarify what you mean when you say "I am connected to my SQL server" ? are you connecting from the same machine that is showing the problem? as the same Windows account?

Comment: The error message had things for you to check and try. Which of the have you checked / tried?

Comment: i am using windows authentication in SSMS

Comment: Put a breakpoint at line `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);` and see what connection string you have. Can you show us the connection string?

Comment: I added the breakpoint and this is the result @TheVillageIdiot https://imgur.com/a/NuxLoxL

Comment: How is this question different from your question from [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57867254/70104)?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I forgot to connect to sql server yesterday but this time i am properly connected but still getting the same error

Comment: @yulexa, check if the server name `USER-PC` is the same when you connect to it from *Management Studio*. It may be something like `USER-PC\SqlExpress` or some other name. Also, try using `(local)`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I checked it.. https://imgur.com/a/aws69dB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. The connection string in config file should contain `data source=.\sqlexpress` not `USER-PC`:

`<add name="Project.Properties.Settings.QuestionDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

[image: Management Studio Connection]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the connection string is correct (test it with mssqlmanager). And then make sure you have your server properly configured, and make sure the firewall is also properly configured. If the server is remote, make sure you can ping it first so you know the connection is valid. If you're running local - double check all configurations, cause that must be the problem.

[How to enable the named pipes/tcp](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm)

[How to configure the firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Please when downvoting, also explain why - how can I ever improve my answer?